# SQL - Query fails *unless* string is broken up into number and letters and then concatenated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, quickbooks-online

I have the following SQL query that returns an invoice by `DocNumber`:

`"SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = '" . $id . "'"`

Here, `$id` contains a string like the following examples:

```
M10045
M10046
M10046
```

This query fails **unless** I separate `$id` into `'M'` and `'10045'` and concatenate them in the query like so:

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $id, $id_number, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $id, $id_letter, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

"SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = '" . $id_letter[0][0] . $id_number[0][0] . "'"
```

What could cause this kind of problem?

Note, using `$id` in the query returns an empty array due to no matches being found. Splitting apart the letter and number portion of the `$id` returns an invoice object.

Comment: Are you sure there is no new line/tab-character in $id?

Comment: What does you data look like?  Possible space between the M and the number

Comment: What is the return value of echo `count($id);`?

Comment: you might need to trim() the value if there is a trailing space or other whitespace at the end of $id that you can't see.

Comment: There must be some sort of weird character because using preg_match with `/\w+/` also works.

Comment: trim() is the best solution I think. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't be generating the sql query manually like this, you should be doing parameterized queries, which may avoid situations like this also.

Comment: Where does the parameter come from? If it is from user input, you may have a SQL injection vulnerability here.

Comment: The parameter is not from user input.  However, I will be using prepared SQL statements in the future if for no other reason than to prevent headaches like these from reoccuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
$id =  trim($id);
```

or

```
$id =  preg_replace('/[^\w]/', '', $id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber = '$id'";
```

to remove all characters that are not AlphaNum dashes or underscores.

Comment: I think trim() is the best solution, however.

Comment: The solution above will also remove meta stuff such as carriage and newlines, just keep that in mind.